# IE protected mode third party cookie issue

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

I am seeing a weird issue in certain IE9 browsers (not every browser). I drop a cookie to another domain using an iframe and all the cookies is set proprely at that time but when i am visiting the other domain the cookie is magically gone.

This all works fine when i removed the protected mode. And it only happens on certian ie9 browsers.

I got all the p3p set properly and to make sure it's not p3p issue i have set the privacy to accept all cookies and it still re-pros.

Answer (score 4):

It's due to mixed zones.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/10/internet-explorer-beware-cookie-sharing-in-cross-zone-scenarios.aspx